# How to use beans inside classes that are not managed by the Micronaut?

Tags: java, hibernate, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have an entity with a `created by` field and I need to populate this field using the `AuthenticatedUserService` that I created. I need to inject this service in the entity such that I can generate the value for the `created by` field.

This is my Authenticated User Service

```
@Singleton
public class AuthenticatedUserService {

@Inject
private SecurityService securityService;

public String getUserIdentifier() {
    var authentication = securityService.getAuthentication();

    return String.valueOf(authentication.get().getAttributes().get("identifier"));
}
```

And I tried injecting the service in an entity using `@Transient`. But this returns NullPointerException for the instance of AuthenticatedUserService. The entity looks like this.

```
@Entity(name = "car")
public class Car {
...
private String createdBy;

@Transient
@Inject
AuthenticatedUserService authenticatedUserService;

...  

 @PrePersist
 public void prePersist() {
    this.createdBy = authenticatedUserService.getUserIdentifier();
 }
}
```

Is there a way I can use the AuthenticatedUserService inside classes that aren't managed by the Micronaut?

I wish to do something like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring) but in Micronaut.

Comment: I don't know Micronaut but this is usually not possible because the Entitiy is not a managed class of the dependency injection framework. This is managed by Hibernate

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll edit my question accordingly to identify a way to use a bean managed by the Micronaut inside classes that are beyond its scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a way to do this. We need the instance of `ApplicationContext` to do this

```
public class ApplicationEntryPoint {

public static ApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = Micronaut.run();
 }
}
```

Then I created a utility that extracts beans from the `ApplicationContext`

```
public class BeanUtil{
 public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
    return EntryPoint.context.getBean(beanClass);
 }
}
```

Finally, extracted the bean of AuthenticatedUserService in the Entity using the`BeanUtil`.

```
@Entity(name = "car")
public class Car {
...
private String createdBy;

...  

 @PrePersist
 public void prePersist() {
 var authenticatedUserService = BeanUtil.getBean(AuthenticatedUserService.class);
  this.createdBy = authenticatedUserService.getUserIdentifier();
 }
}
```

Comment: Will the context be available when running the tests though ?